# focus() on contentEditable element in Angular not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, focus

Everytime when the machines Array is refreshed, and the UI is refreshed I lose the focus on the card title and I can't refocus on it:

Machine.Component.html:

```
<mat-card-title #rxjsSelector contentEditable="true" [textContent]="name" (input)="title=$event.target.textContent">
    Name:{{name}}</mat-card-title>
```

Machine.Component.ts:

```
  @ViewChild('rxjsSelector', { static: false }) titleElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.titleElement.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .subscribe(res => {
          this.socket.sendMessageChange({ id: this.id, name: this.name });
          this.titleElement.nativeElement.focus(); ///// NOT WORKING
          //tried also .open() or click();
      });
  }
```

MachineList.component.html:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let m of machines; let i = index" class="flex-item">
    <app-machine [name]="m.name" [id]="m.id"></app-machine>
</mat-card>
```

MachineList.Component.ts:

```
private machines: Machine[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.scoketService.getMessage().subscribe(m => {
      let index = this.machines.findIndex(localM => {
        return m.id === localM.id;
      });
      if (index === -1) {
        this.machines.push(m);
      } else {
        this.machines[index] = m;
      }
    });}
```

Comment: I see where you have one line of code not working, but what is it you are trying to do? I suspect the line might not be getting hit.

Comment: @theMayer no no the line is being hit for sure :) the focus() is not working! because the UI changes depending on the this.machines[] array...

Comment: Hi @Suisse please comment when you see this message so it can get deleted. Would you be open to consulting on issues related to Quill? For instance, our newest issue is dealing with leading/trailing whitespace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165825/how-to-detect-and-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-quill-rich-text-editor.