# How to detect and trim leading/trailing whitespace in Quill (rich text editor)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rich-text-editor, quill

How can you detect and delete leading/trailing whitespace in [Quill](https://quilljs.com/), which is a rich text editor?

For instance, the sample **HTML** below represents **Quill** output for the text `"\nHi"`.

We want to detect and delete leading and trailing whitespace for each block of the text created by **Quill** (not for an entire document). Basically, trim leading/trailing whitespace for each embedded **Quill** editor. (We embed multiple editors within the same page.)

> The *API* doesn't seem to offer a simple way to achieve this and would require some hacking?
>
> Is there an elegant way to trim text with **Quill** effectively?

```html
<div class="ql-editor" 
     data-gramm="false" 
     contenteditable="true" 
     spellcheck="false" 
     autocomplete="off" 
     autocorrect="off" 
     autocapitalize="off">
   <p style="align-self: center;">
       <br>
   </p>
   <p style="align-self: center;">
        <span style="font-family: Lato; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 80px; line-height: 1.5; letter-spacing: 0em; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal;">Hi&nbsp;</span>
     </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce this in https://quilljs.com/playground/ . Mind providing a working example?

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut thanks for the reply! did you include the newline before "hi'? with two lines in the quill playground (first line is newline; second line is "hi"), the html output has two <p> elements as indicated in the question.

Comment: yes I did. Here the output: `<div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Compose an epic..."><p><br></p><p>Hello</p></div>`

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut ah the leading `<p><br></p>` is the whitespace we want to trim. basically, we don't want any entries with leading/trailing `<p><br></p>` parts. do you know how to hook into quill and parse these values from the html output? thanks again for your help!

Comment: Do you want to remove leading and trailing whitespaces for all text  blocks or just at the beginning and at ending of complete quill editor. Your requirement is not so clear, can you please explain by giving a good example? Let say i have text "\n Hi \n Crashalot \n \n Bye \n"

Comment: But this is the line break you just enter... it is not something that Quill does. You want to disable new lines at the beginning?

Comment: @Crashalot when do you want the whitespace clearance to happen? immediately as the user types the text or when you get the contents using `quill.getText()` or `quill.getContents()`?

Comment: @ChristosLytras it can be either `quill.getText()` or `quill.getContents()`. it should not happen in real-time as the user types. thanks!

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut remove new lines from the start and the end.

Comment: @Prince hi thanks for helping (also cool username)! remove from beginning and end of a complete quill editor. (we have multiple quill editors per page.) in your example, the first and last `\n` should be removed, but the others preserved.

Comment: I got your point, but the user is responsible for entering that extra newline. It could be done intentionally by the user. So, I would suggest to keep it as it is. But if you still want to remove it, then at what point ?? I mean when ?? when user enters any data as soon you want to remove it or when user blurs out of quill editor??

Comment: @Prince when the user blurs out of the quill editor. thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Crashalot did you check my answer? Doesn't it cover you detection/conversion needs? What exactly do you mean by *effectively*?

Answer (score 5):

Quill uses the [Delta](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) class to describe the rich text format and we can use Quill [`getContents`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getcontents) method to get all content entries which will be in the following format:

```js
Delta {
  ops: [
    insert: "↵↵↵Hello↵world!↵↵"
  ]
}
```

We have to create a logic using a loop through all these entries, detect and eliminate leading and ending line feeds.

We use two arrays, one array that we'll store the new delta entries and one for storing the pending ending line feeds that we may or may not append to the new delta entries array. We'll also have a flag indicating whether we've fixed the leading line feeds.

This solution uses this method ["handling blur event"](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1680#issuecomment-348888456) to detect the blur event.

#### Quill blur code and snippet (*run to see it in action*):

<sup>*Please read inline comments*</sup>

```js
let quills = [];

[...document.getElementsByClassName('quill-editor')].forEach((el, idx) => {
  const quill = new Quill(el, {
    modules: {
      toolbar: [
        [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
        ['image', 'code-block']
      ]
    },
    placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
    theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
  });

  quill.on('selection-change', function(range, oldRange, source) {
    if (range === null && oldRange !== null) {
      const delta = quill.getContents();

      let leadingFixed = false;
      let newDelta = [];
      let tempDelta = [];

      if(delta.ops.length === 1) {
        // If there is only one entry, check if it's a string and trim leading and ending LF
        let { insert, attributes } = delta.ops[0];
        if(typeof(insert) === 'string') {
          insert = insert.replace(/^\n+|\n+$/g, '');
        }
        newDelta = [{ insert, attributes }];
      } else {
        // Else go through all the insert entries
        delta.ops.forEach(({ insert, attributes }, idx) => {
          // Create a boolean to indicate if we're at the last entry
          const isLast = idx === delta.ops.length - 1;

          // If the entry is a string (not image/asset)
          if(typeof(insert) === 'string') {
            // If we haven't fixed the leading
            if(!leadingFixed) {
              // If the entry begins with LFs
              if(/^\n+/.test(insert)) {
                // Create a string witrh clean leading LFs
                let cleanText = insert.replace(/^\n+/, '');

                // If there is text after cleaning the LFs
                if(cleanText.length > 0) {
                  // Add the text to the newDelta
                  newDelta.push({
                    insert: cleanText,
                    attributes
                  });
                  // Set leading flag to indicate we've fixed the leading
                  leadingFixed = true;
                }
              // Else if the entry does not start with LFs
              } else {
                // If the entry does not begin with LFs
                // Add any pending entries that may exists in tempDelta to the newDelta
                newDelta = newDelta.concat(tempDelta);
                // Add the existing entry
                newDelta.push({
                  insert,
                  attributes
                });
                // Clean the any pending entries
                tempDelta = [];
                // And set the leading flag to indicate we've fixed the leading
                leadingFixed = true;
              }
            // Else if we have fixed the leading
            } else {
              // If there an entry with ending LFs
              if(/\n+$/.test(insert)) {
                // Create a string witrh clean ending LFs
                let cleanText = insert.replace(/\n+$/, '');

                // If this is the last entry
                if(isLast) {
                  // If there is text after cleaning the LFs
                  if(cleanText.length > 0) {
                    // Add any pending entries that may exists in tempDelta to the newDelta
                    newDelta = newDelta.concat(tempDelta);
                    // Add the cleaned entry
                    newDelta.push({
                      insert: cleanText,
                      attributes
                    });
                  }
                // Else if this is not the last entry
                } else {
                  // If there is text after cleaning the LFs
                  if(cleanText.length > 0) {
                    // Add any pending entries that may exists in tempDelta to the newDelta
                    newDelta = newDelta.concat(tempDelta);
                    // Add the existing entry
                    newDelta.push({
                      insert,
                      attributes
                    });
                    // Clean the any pending entries
                    tempDelta = [];
                  // Else if there is no text after cleaning the LFs
                  } else {
                    // Add the entry to the temp deltas so to use them later if its needed
                    tempDelta.push({ insert, attributes });
                  }
                }
              // Else if the entry does not end with LFs
              } else {
                // Add any pending entries that may exists in tempDelta to the newDelta
                newDelta = newDelta.concat(tempDelta);
                // Add the existing entry
                newDelta.push({
                  insert,
                  attributes
                });
                // Clean the any pending entries
                tempDelta = [];
              }
            }
          // If the entry is not a string
          } else {
            // Then all leading text/line feeds have been cleared if there were any
            // so, it's safe to set the leading flag
            leadingFixed = true;
            // Add any pending entries that may exists in tempDelta to the newDelta
            newDelta = newDelta.concat(tempDelta);
            // Add the existing entry
            newDelta.push({
              insert,
              attributes
            })
            // Clean the any pending entries
            tempDelta = [];
          }
        });
      }

      quill.setContents(newDelta);
    } /*else if (range !== null && oldRange === null) {
      console.log('focus');
    }*/
  });

  quills.push(quill);
});
```

```css
.editors {
  display: flex;
}

.quill-editor-container {
  flex: 1;
}
.quill-editor {
  height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.core.js" integrity="sha256-jvauzib5XGeoiDyHV6mlZnpuKsEAcjhruilbo0e+L6k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.js" integrity="sha256-CN8TogJAzCcMj0uYishm9mmawPUFKJeJh//zR/CfCO8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.core.css" integrity="sha256-2kIq+5smyR4blGwdXXCCVrPLENwavLyrG8+kLPfDPJk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.bubble.css" integrity="sha256-2hxHujXw890GumwDHPWrwJCtdZZdrJanlGsrOTSfXnc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.snow.css" integrity="sha256-jyIuRMWD+rz7LdpWfybO8U6DA65JCVkjgrt31FFsnAE=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="editors">
  <div class="quill-editor-container"><div class="quill-editor"></div></div>
  <div class="quill-editor-container"><div class="quill-editor"></div></div>
</div>
```

I've tested it with image assets and formatting and it seems to work pretty well. Of course the code can be further optimized and maybe simplified.

You can also check this [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quill-lf-trim?file=index.html) if you wanna fork it and make some tests.